# Android overlay an image/wrap image inside another image

Tags: android, image, android-layout

In Android, preferably in XML is it possible to overlay an image around another image?

I have an image which is a blue circle and My app retrieves an icon from an API. After the icon has been retrieved it is displayed via an ImageView.

The XML for the ImageView is:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Now I would like to "wrap" an image around this image. The XML for the image I want around the retrieved image is:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image_wrap"/>
```

Comment: what exactly your looking for? you want a blue circle around your image (or) you want to place a image around a image ?

Comment: An image (which happens to be a blue circle) around an image

Comment: Set the blue circle as `background` and the icon as `src` of the same `ImageView`. If necesseary play with padding.